# How do I write a plugin to get the account creation date, total number of users & total number of licensed users in Jenkins?

Tags: email, jenkins, plugins, licensing, userid

I am trying to write a plugin for Jenkins to get the account creation date, total number of users, and total number of licensed users. I am having difficulty understanding how I can access the necessary data and create the plugin to display the required information. I tried searching for a solution, but I couldn't find one.

I've tried something like this:

```java
import hudson.model.User;

String user = User.current();
String mailAddress = user.getMailAddress();
```

Is there a way to get the same thing mentioned above?

Comment: No, because Jenkins is not a licensed product, so that will always be 0. Also, you don't need a plugin, just run the groovy script from the `/script` page.

Comment: The method of interest is [User.AllUsers](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/User.html)